# ProgressDialog and AsyncTask at abnormal behavior fails

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a AsyncTasc which turns of ProgressDialog, all works great, but after some time of abnormal behavior app fails. I know, that user will never behave so. But for good testing is necessary to try all.

Code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    GetSubs gs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Log.d("Called on Cancel", " Listener");
                gs.cancel(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Clicked(View view) {
        gs = new GetSubs();
        gs.execute();
    }

    public class GetSubs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Log.d("onPreExecute", " in AsyncTasc");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCancelled();
            Log.d("onCancelled", " in AsyncTasc");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("onPostExecute", " in AsyncTasc");

        }

    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:751)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:474)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:163)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:348)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:139)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:333)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at com.example.getusersubs.MainActivity$GetSubs.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:82)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at com.example.getusersubs.MainActivity$GetSubs.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-16 21:14:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28767):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is wrong? Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("onPostExecute", " in AsyncTasc");

    }
```

to

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Log.d("onPostExecute", " in AsyncTasc");

    }
```

The problem is that you are trying to dismiss a progress-dialog without checking if it is showing or not, the user can cancel that dialog easily by pressing `backKey`.

Still you can force the user to wait for the dialog by setting [Cancellable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29) to false. that way the back-key will have no effect.

Comment: After change it still fails, but `setCancellable()` solved my problem. Thank you for explanation.